# E/F finite extension F'/F any extension. EF' composite field. Prove [EF':F']<=[E:F]

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, extension-field

As the question says (we assume E and F' are contained in some field so that the composite EF' is well-defined). I've thought of trying to prove this using indiction by writing E=F(a1,...ar) but unfortunately I haven't really been able to get onto the right track and cant seem to quite get to the answer. Do you know of any hints/ways to solve this problem? Thank you for any comments or answers.

EDIT: I have now managed to solve the base case E=F(a).

Comment: Can you do the case $E=F(a)$?

Comment: Im currently trying: Let the degree of a over F be n, so that [F(a):F]=n. Then we have to show that [F(a)F':F']<=n. Im stuck on proving that statement

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ has in particular coefficients in $F'$.

Comment: Why is this so?

Comment: Oh no i understand why now it has coefficients as F is subfield of F'

Comment: Oh i think I've proved the base case now as [F(a)F':F']=n fufilling the hypothesis that [F(a)F':F']<=[F(a):F]

Comment: actually I meant [F(a)F':F']<=n as [F(a):F']<=n as the minimal polynomial of a over F has coefficients in F'.

Comment: Now the general case is just a trivial corollary: note that you have inclusions $F \subset F(a_1) \subset F(a_1,a_2) \subset \dotsc$ and the base case tells you that in each step the degree gets smaller if you have the same inclusions with $F'$ instead of $F$.

Comment: Could you explain please how the base case tells you that in each step the degree gets smaller if you have the same inclusions with F′ instead of F.

Comment: Each step is a simple field extension, so you can apply the base step to each case. Honestly, I do not see your problem there.

Answer (score -1):

lets assum that F'=F(x), then EF=EF(x)=E(x), the minimal polynomial of x over F (say f) is a polynomial in E[X], so the minimal polynomial of x over E must devise f, so [EF':E]<=[F':F].